ipywidgets Vbox not visible in the Binder Deployment using Voila
I am trying to deploy a Jupyter notebook using Voila on Binder on this link. The notebook is working perfectly fine on my local notebook and it also works perfectly fine when I run it as a standalone app on my system using voila. But when I open the deployed version on Binder, I can't see the widget added for uploading the images (Refer to this image)
I have tried many debugging options from the forum discussions I could find and modified my postBuild and ProcFile according to that but I am not able to fix this. Here is a link to my GitHub. I am trying to deploy the app.ipynb file.
requirements.txt
opencv-python-headless==4.5.3.56
matplotlib==3.4.3
numpy==1.21.2
pillow==7.0.0
bokeh==2.1.1
torch==1.11.0
torchvision==0.12.0
tqdm==4.63.0
ipywidgets==7.6.5
livelossplot==0.5.4
pytest==7.1.1
pandas==1.3.5
seaborn==0.11.2
voila

runtime.txt
python-3.7.6

postBuild
pip install -U ipywidgets
npm install
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter serverextension enable --sys-prefix voila

ProcFile
web: voila --port=$PORT --no-browser --Voila.ip=0.0.0.0 app.ipynb


Update: Checked the console and saw this error Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules:. Added a javascript command in app.ipynb to increase waitSeconds to 60 but the output remains the same

It works fine. You probably didn't refresh fully? See https://imgur.com/a/qy29RAp where you'll see it showing and I was able to upload an image and run the 'identify' button on it. That was from a fresh MyBinder launch just now.
